# Missing letters when using Google Apps Script to send SMS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using the following code to send an SMS (via Gmail) to a phone number stored in Range("A1") in Sheets:

```
  function sendTextMessagesWithGatewayTest() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  // Get the range of phone numbers
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1"); // Adjust the range as per your data
  
  // Get the values from the range
  var phoneNumbers = range.getValues();
  
  // Loop through each phone number
  for (var i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.length; i++) {
    var phoneNumber = parsePhoneNumber(phoneNumbers[i][0]); // Parse phone number
    
    // Test each gateway domain before sending the text message
    var result = testGatewayDomains(phoneNumber);
    
    // If at least one gateway domain test was successful, send the text message
    if (result.isValid) {
      sendTextMessageGateway(phoneNumber, "This is the message", result.domain); // Pass the domain to the sendTextMessageGateway function
    } else {
      Logger.log('Unable to send text message to phone number: ' + phoneNumber + '. No valid gateway domains found.');
    }
  }
}

function testGatewayDomains(phoneNumber) {
  var gatewayDomains = {
    'Bell Mobility': 'txt.bell.ca',
    'Rogers Wireless': 'pcs.rogers.com',
    'Telus Mobility': 'msg.telus.com',
    'Fido': 'fido.ca',
    'Koodo Mobile': 'msg.koodomobile.com',
    'Virgin Mobile Canada': 'vmobile.ca'
    // Add more carriers and their respective gateway domains as needed
  };
  
  // Loop through each carrier and its corresponding gateway domain
  for (var carrier in gatewayDomains) {
    if (gatewayDomains.hasOwnProperty(carrier)) {
      var domain = gatewayDomains[carrier];
      
      // Construct URL to check if domain is reachable
      var url = 'http://' + domain;
      
      try {
        // Send HTTP GET request to the URL
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
        
        // Check response code
        if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
          // Log success if request was successful
          Logger.log('Domain is reachable: ' + domain);
          return { isValid: true, domain: domain }; // Exit function early if at least one domain is reachable
        } else {
          // Log error if request was not successful
          Logger.log('Domain is not reachable: ' + domain + ' (Response code: ' + response.getResponseCode() + ')');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // Log error if request failed
        Logger.log('Error checking domain: ' + domain + ' - ' + error);
      }
    }
  }
  return { isValid: false, domain: null }; // Return false if no reachable domains found
}

function sendTextMessageGateway(phoneNumber, message, workingDomain) {
  var recipient = phoneNumber + "@" + workingDomain; 
  var subject = "Notification"; // Provide a subject for the email
  Logger.log('Recipient: ' + recipient); 
  
  // Send the email
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message);
}

function parsePhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
  // Remove non-numeric characters
  var parsedNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, '');
  
  return parsedNumber;
}
```

While this does work in that it sends the SMS, every instance of the letter "s" is missing so the message looks like "Thi i the meage" instead of "This is the message". Can anybody explain what's going on here and how I could potentially alter this code to avoid this issue?

Comment: It looks like what your code actually does, is send an _email_ to addresses of the form `phonenumber@carrier-endpoint`, and then those individual carriers are in charge of actually "translating" that email content into an SMS, sent to their customer. Are you having this problem with all of your potential carriers - or just with one of them, that the mobile number you are currently testing with, belongs to ...? Looks to me like the issue is probably on the receiving end.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too. Just curious if there was a workaround, possibly by encoding the message, but I'd need to ensure that the carrier can properly decode the result. I've tried (unsuccessfully) to convert the message to Base64, but the received message ends up in Base64, not decoded.

Comment: I don't know if this is based on any sort of specification, or if it is something the mobile carriers more or less came up with on their own. But if the "input" basically works by sending an email - then I cant imagine that it requires any special encoding of the message, it should probably work for wherever one might send an email from. Only thing I could imagine that it perhaps expects a certain encoding of the mail content itself - a common format like quoted-printable perhaps, but that `GmailApp.sendEmail` perhaps sends something different.

Comment: What happens when you send the same message to the same recipient address, directly from your own desktop mail client for example?

Comment: I get the same result, with every "s" omitted.

Comment: Did you just test with of those "gateway domains" in particular, or multiple / all of them?

Comment: I've only tested with a couple of them (given that I am testing, I'm sending these messages to trusted individuals and those individuals are with Bell and Virgin).

Comment: It works with Telus!